# R, generate number vector only contains 0 and 1, with certain length

Tags: r

I wanted to create a list/vector like this:

```
c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

or

```
c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1)
```

the length of this vector is a variable 'X', and the position of 0 and 1 are totally random.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done via sampling *with replacement* from the set of binary digits:

```
n <- 10 # sample size
sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n)
```

On a side note, if you wish - for whatever reason - to reproduce exactly the two above vectors, you will need to change the random number generator's seed:

```
set.seed(194842)
sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=21)
## [1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

set.seed(153291)
sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=17)
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: A little trick.  You can also write `sample(2)-1` so that you don't have to write `c(0,1)` in `sample`.  I think it's also a bit faster

Comment: If `size` is big then it will not be faster because `-1` will result in extra allocation an a loop. Also there is `sample.int` if one wants speed.

Answer (score 31):

```
X <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)
```

It is a random binomial deviate generator function which will create a vector 'X' of length 20 containing '0' and '1' with success probability of 0.5. Here is the output.

```
> X
 [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```